# Why cannot devide

Tags: html, smarty

Why this fragment of code works:

```
<TD width="10%" ..............

{if ............} PRINT <BR>  

    {else}
    {if $a>=$b} something {$a-$b-86400|date_format:"%d"} days {/if}
    {/if}

</TD>
```

but this one doesn't:

```
<TD width="10%" ..............

{if ............} PRINT <BR>

    {else}
    {if $a>=$b} something {($a-$b)/2|date_format:"%d"} days {/if}
    {/if}

</TD>
```

I have only changed this equation $a-$b-86400 to ($a-$b)/2 and site doesn't work.

Comment: ($a-$b)/2  need to be (($a-$b)/2)

Comment: This isn't even valid PHP code. Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: I am not certain if `date_format` accepts a float as input. You may want to convert that into an integer.

Comment: (($a-$b)/2) still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
{if $a>=$b} something {(($a-$b)/2)|ceil|date_format:"%d"} days {/if}
```

As mentioned in the comments put the calculation in brackets and since decimals shouldn't be valid in a timestamp: round it up with `|ceil`

Comment: It still doesn't working. Only this works:  
`{if $a>=$b} something {$a-$b/2|ceil|date_format:"%d"} days {/if}`  
When I use brackets it crashed.

Comment: try it with `$a` and `$b` as plain integers, instead of variables, I suspect your variables don't get parsed correctly. The example above works perfectly for me.